# Addthis: Print icon not displaying on iPad

Tags: ios, ipad, printing, sharing, addthis

I am using Addthis sharing buttons on my site. On an iPad, the print button is not rendering, in both Safari and Chrome. All the other buttons are working fine.

Only the iPad is giving me this issue. Every other device/browser is fine.